# How to access code of a specific page in shopify?

Tags: shopify, liquid

I am building a Shopify website https://fone-kase-plus.myshopify.com/.
For example, I want to modify code of this page only:  https://fone-kase-plus.myshopify.com/pages/iphone-6 .

How is it possible to do it?

Answer (score 0):

If you go in the admin, and to that page (from Online Store/Pages) on the right you will see "Theme Template" and a name. That's the template that is applied to that page.

That name is a file in your theme under templates with a name like `page.your-template-name.liquid`.

If you copy that file and create another one like `page.another-template-name.liquid` you can then apply that template only to the pages you want. Then you modify that template file to make a page as you like.